# CSS / HTML Parameter link

Tags: html, css

i found this template in themeforest site http://designova.net/reveal/preview/.
i try to explore that template and i found link like this:
http://designova.net/reveal/preview/index.html#filter=.blog%3Anot(.blog2),+.post2

can you tell me about this link params

```
#filter=.blog%3Anot(.blog2),+.post2
```

i haven't see link like that before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This site uses [jquery-bbq](https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-bbq/) and [jquery-isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/).

With *jquery-bbq*, it parses the url, and gets a result as a *filter*.

With *jquery-isotope* and the *filter*, it filter items in this site with animation. The mechanism of *jquery-isotope* is:

> Filtering: Hide and reveal item elements easily with jQuery selectors.

Answer (score 0):

When the page loads, JavaScript looks at the value after the hash, then updates the view to that filter. The `%3A` is encoding for a colon, so the filter value is:

```
.blog:not(.blog2),+.post2
```

The `.blog` is a class selector, so look for all `.blog` that isn't `.blog2` then also show the element with a class name of `post2`.

Try going to the following URLs and you'll see how the content is different:

- http://designova.net/reveal/preview/index.html

  - *Show me everything*
- http://designova.net/reveal/preview/index.html#filter=.blog

  - *Only show me blog posts (elements with a `blog` class)*
- http://designova.net/reveal/preview/index.html#filter=.blog%3Anot(.blog2)

  - *Show me all blog posts with a `blog` class but exclude those with a `blog2` class*
- http://designova.net/reveal/preview/index.html#filter=.blog%3Anot(.blog2),+.post2

  - *Same as the 3rd link, but also show me the post with the class of `post2`*